# Webpack Alias and ES6 imports / exports

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

This is a two part question.

I have set up a Webpack alias named `controls` to a particular files that  houses all of my shared React components. This file is simply a index.js file that imports all of the desired components (approximately 30 shared components) and then exports them like:

`export { Button, Tabs, ProgressBar, Carousel, … }`

The components are from various places (libraries, mine, etc). My understanding of imports is that if I write

`import { Button } from ‘controls';`

anywhere in my project where I want to use `Button`, only `Button` should be pulled into my dependency tree - not every export from 'controls/index.js'.

**First Question: is my understanding of the way imports / exports should be working here accurate?**

Now for the problem: all of the components, whether they are used in a particular bundle or not, are being pulled into every bundle. I am pretty sure that this is happening because of my Webpack alias.

**Second Question: anyone have any advice on how I can still cleanly import multiple shared components on a single line like**

`import { Button, Tabs, InitialsAvatar } from 'controls';`

**but not pull all of my controls (aka shared React components) into the dependency tree?**

I have played around with Webpack's `moduleDirectores` and `root`, but these have not allowed me to import multiple components on a single line and don't allow me to use a single index.js file to house all of my shared components.

Comment: webpack v1 doesn't do tree shaking, if that's what you thought.

Comment: @FelixKling ok so the issue is at least partly (if not entirely) with Webpack 1, but do ES6 's import / exports have a native behavior as far as **only** importing the needed slice of the module or is the behavior entirely dependent up your module builder (webpack 1, webpack 2, systemjs, etc)

Comment: It depends on the module bundler. ES6 expects the whole module to be evaluated when any export is imported.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to webpack 2+, it supports tree-shaking.

Now Webpack 2+ only marks code unused and doesn’t export it inside the module. It pulls everything and leaves unused code for minification libraries.

You can use [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) with babel for this.
UglifyJS doesn’t support the new language features of Javascript ES2015+ yet. You will need Babel to transpile the code to ES5 and then use UglifyJS to clean up the unused code.

You will need .babelrc file with:

We have to tell the preset (in our case [babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/)) to skip the module transpilation.

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "loose": true,
      "modules": false
    }]
  ]
}
```

and corresponding webpack config:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
  ]
},

plugins: [
  new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    minimize: true,
    debug: false
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
      warnings: true
    },
    output: {
      comments: false
    },
    sourceMap: false
  })
]
```

**OR**

[Babili](https://github.com/babel/minify) is a better option since Babili will remove unused code before transpilation. It is much easier to spot unused classes before downleveled to ES5. Tree-shaking will also work for class declarations, not just functions.

You will need:

npm install [babili](https://babeljs.io/blog/2016/08/30/babili) [babili-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/babel-minify-webpack-plugin) --save-dev

Use the following plugin in your webpack config, like so:

```
plugins: [
  new BabiliPlugin()
]
```

There is also an optimzied way to use babili as a preset. You can refer their site to use it as a preset for babel-loader.